# Learning to use execute block in Firebird with a simple example

Tags: sql, firebird, execute

I haven't used yet execute block in Firebird, but Im struggling to learn how to use it.

I am trying to learn from a simple example and then will expand to a more complex situation.

Suppose I have 2 tables like below:

```
+------------+------+
| Clientcode | name |
+------------+------+
|        123 | A    |
|        234 | B    |
+------------+------+
```

```
+----------+------------+---------+
| order_id | clientcode |  value  |
+----------+------------+---------+
|       12 |        234 |  10,00  |
|       13 |        123 |  20,00  |
|       14 |        123 |  10,00  |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

I have the following code.

```
execute block returns (client integer,amount double)
as
declare variable  client_code integer;
begin
for
select clientcode from clients
into  : client_code
do
begin
select :client_code,sum(value) from orders group by 1
into :client, :order_id;
end
end
```

Basically, I want for every client in the client table to calculate the sum of the orders in the orders table. I know that it is not necessary execute block in this case, but with a simple example I might be able to understand it better.

```
+-------------+--------+
| client_code | amount |
+-------------+--------+
|         123 |     30 |
|         234 |     10 |
+-------------+--------+
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: start with reading about **stored procedures**. Essentially EB is one-time ad hoc nameless SP.  Stored procedures were in Interbase/Firebird for decades and there are lot of information about them, historically. In books, in forums, in FAQs, everywhere. When you make yourself easy with SPs - then EBs are all just the same but without names and without persistence. So simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things missing in your code:

1. You need a `where`-clause when selecting from `orders` to limit it to only the rows of the current client
2. You need to output the sum to `amount`, not to the non-existent variable `order_id`
3. You need to add [`suspend`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-suspend) to output a row (otherwise an execute block can only produces a single row, with the last values assigned).
4. (optional) You don't need the variable `client_code` when `client` fulfills the same purpose

The resulting code would be something like (note that I used `decimal(18,2)` instead of `double precision`, using exact precision numeric types like `decimal` is a better choice for money values):

```
execute block returns (client_code integer,amount decimal(18,2))
as
begin
  for select clientcode from clients 
    into client_code
  do
  begin
    select sum(amount) from orders where clientcode = :client_code
      into amount;
    suspend;
  end
end
```

This is the equivalent of the following query:

```
select clients.clientcode as client_code, sum(orders.amount) as amount
from clients
left join orders on clients.clientcode = orders.clientcode
group by clients.clientcode
```

See also this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=fa050e27121b3b976a58709683cc3fc4).

Keep in mind, [`execute block`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock) is essentially a Firebird stored procedure that isn't stored. An `execute block` with a `suspend` behaves as a [selectable procedure](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-storedprocs-selectable) which can produce zero or more rows, and one without `suspend` behaves as an [executable procedure](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-storedprocs-executable) which can produce one row only.